# Grunt/Batch : how to execute shell commands within the gruntfile.js directory?

Tags: windows, gruntjs, dos, grunt-shell

I know this is a common question but all answers I tried didn't work. What's strange is that a friend tried this script on his Windows and actually got the current directory (the one containing the gruntfile.js). I tried to see the differences but I also didn't find any.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        shell: {
            test: {
                command: 'dir'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
};
```

Here is what I get :

```
D:\Websites\AUB>grunt shell:test
Running "shell:test" (shell) task
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 6E7B-40AB

 Directory of D:\Websites

04/22/2015  04:53 PM    <DIR>          .
04/22/2015  04:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/20/2015  11:04 AM    <DIR>          .sublime
03/30/2015  12:52 PM    <DIR>          .template
04/24/2015  07:55 AM    <DIR>          AUB
```

I tried to use the trick from [this post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/08/12/getting-the-current-working-directory-from-dos-or-batch-file/) but the it didn't work (I stay in Websites directory) :

```
command: 'set WORKING_DIRECTORY=%cd% && dir'
```

I also tried to find something useful with ["Get directory containing the currently executed batch script"](https://serverfault.com/questions/255291/get-directory-containing-the-currently-executed-batch-script), but I don't see how to use it since I got errors :

```
command: 'cd %~dp0 && dir'
```

which returns :

```
D:\Websites\AUB>grunt shell:test
Running "shell:test" (shell) task
The system cannot find the path specified.
Warning: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "cd %~dp0 && dir"
The system cannot find the path specified.
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

As a side-note, any other package I'm using straight from Grunt (clean, copy, rename, uglify, etc) is working just fine and grunt-exec has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds strange as usually all plugins work relative to your Gruntfile:

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file

> Note: all file paths are relative to the Gruntfile unless the current
>   working directory is changed with grunt.file.setBase or the --base
>   command-line option.

You could retrieve the current work manually:

```
var cwd process.cwd()

// Or to get a file inside the cwd    

var pathOfGruntfile = require('path').resolve('./Gruntfile.js');
```

and use it in your Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        cwd: process.cwd(),

        shell: {
            test: {
                command: 'cd "<%= cwd %>";dir'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
};
```

Comment: Thank you @jantimon ! I guess that there is something wrong with my cmd.exe config. This trick does perfectly work and has the advantage to stay multi-platforms friendly.